# Generate Asciidoc files with custom visual style

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, asciidoc

I managed to generate asciidoc files with the generic ui style.

Is it possible to change the default ui style to this ui style: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this:

https://github.com/spring-io/spring-asciidoctor-backends

There are different ways to change the UI.

Comment: Unfortunately I get error `Execution failed for task ':checkFormatMain'.
> Formatting violations found in the following files:` when I try to build it.